# How to suppress the dashed lines in a region where filled circle is drawn?

Tags: python, matplotlib

With the below code, I want to plot two filled circles over the two dashed lines. What I want is that the dashed lines should not be visible in the filled circular region (shown by red) in both the circles. How can I do this in Python ?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 10, 'font.family': 'serif'})
axes = fig.add_subplot(1 ,1 ,1, aspect=1)
axes.set_xlabel("X Position (m)")
axes.set_ylabel("Y Position (m)")

plt.plot([1900e-6,1900e-6], [0,3060e-6], '--',color='black')
plt.plot([2000e-6,2000e-6], [0,3060e-6], '--',color='black')
    
plt.xlim(0,4060e-6) # setting x limits 
plt.ylim(0,3060e-6) # setting y limits

Xcor=np.array([2000e-6,2000e-6])
Ycor=np.array([1000e-6,2500e-6])
Rcor=np.array([547e-6, 447e-6])
            
C=np.vstack((Xcor,Ycor))  # as it is required to be used while making the patches list
C=np.transpose(C)
patches = [plt.Circle(center, size) for center, size in zip(C, Rcor)]
coll = matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection(patches,facecolors='red') # for making filled circles with red colour
axes.add_collection(coll)
plt.show()
```

I am attaching the image produced by the above code.

[image: image produced]

Now what change should be made in the code so that the dashed lines should not be visible in the filled circular region ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the parameter `zorder` to adjust what gets plotted on-top of eachother. Just use `zorder=1` on your when plotting the dashed lines and `zorder=2` on the circles

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 10, 'font.family': 'serif'})
axes = fig.add_subplot(1 ,1 ,1, aspect=1)
axes.set_xlabel("X Position (m)")
axes.set_ylabel("Y Position (m)")

plt.plot([1900e-6,1900e-6], [0,3060e-6], '--',color='black',zorder=1)
plt.plot([2000e-6,2000e-6], [0,3060e-6], '--',color='black', zorder=1)
    
plt.xlim(0,4060e-6) # setting x limits 
plt.ylim(0,3060e-6) # setting y limits

Xcor=np.array([2000e-6,2000e-6])
Ycor=np.array([1000e-6,2500e-6])
Rcor=np.array([547e-6, 447e-6])
            
C=np.vstack((Xcor,Ycor))  # as it is required to be used while making the patches list
C=np.transpose(C)
patches = [plt.Circle(center, size) for center, size in zip(C, Rcor)]
coll = matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection(patches,facecolors='red', zorder=2) # for making filled circles with red colour
axes.add_collection(coll)
plt.show()
```

[image: updated]